# Issues debugging SWFUpload and PHP

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, swfupload

I'm trying to add a SWFUpload instance to my website where multiple files will be uploaded in a queue.  Currently, I'm working in a local LAMP environment running Netbeans and XDebug for my server side work.

I've followed the directions at the site and used [this blog post](http://www.dconstructing.com/2010/07/08/making-swfupload-work) to fill in the blanks.

My issue is that the test uploads execute according to the debug output of SWFUpload, but nothing shows in the upload path.  In debug mode, none of the breakpoints in my server side script get touched.

- I've triple-checked the file paths.
- File permissions are all set to 755

This also occurs when I copied two of the demos to my server instance.  In both circumstances, the `upload_url` php file breakpoints never got touched.

How can I debug this?

**EDIT**

I'm switching to a HTML5 method instead.  however, it would be nice to identify some possible solutions to this issue for others who may run into the same problem.

Comment: Let's see the relevant code ;)

Comment: @vdbuilder, it wasn't so much as the code, but rather the debugger hooks between the Flash code and the server itself.  My setup has worked fine with PHP/JS/Ajax for quite some time, so it was a bit disconcerting to see breakpoints getting skipped for no apparent reason.

Comment: Understood... any errors in the logs?

Comment: @vdbuilder, logging stops after the first queue insert, regardless of the debugger hooked in or not.  Thats why I wanted to debug the server side stuff to make sure it was working.